# Change string with malloc in other function

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc

how can I change string in other function when I am using malloc?

```
in main: 

char *myString;
changeString(myString);


changeString(char *myString){

    myString = malloc((size) * sizeof(char));
    myString[1] = 'a';

}
```

Thank you

Comment: But how should I change pointers inside fuction, because I tried it and it didnt work..

Comment: I dont want to return it

Comment: I searched this on internet, but it didnt work or it wasnt described directly..

Comment: Your function operates on a brand new piece of memory that is allocated and stored in the local variable `myString`. That has no effect on the caller's string. Moreover, it creates a memory leak. The only reference to the newly allocated memory is the `myString` local variable, which goes away when the function terminates. There are numerous questions about this: why modifying a variable in a C function has no effect on the caller's variable.

Answer (score 2):

Parameters in C are passed by value. So to modify a variable within a function, you'll have to pass the pointer to it. For example, `int *` to `int`, and `char **` to `char *`.

```
void changeString(char **myString){
    // free(*myString); // add when myString is allocated using malloc()
    *myString = malloc(2);
    (*myString)[0] = 'a';
    (*myString)[1] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Allocate memory in main, then pass a pointer to start of allocated memory to the function.
Also pass a variable containing the size of the allocated memory to the function, so that you can ensure that the new text does not overflow the allocated memory.
The modified string is available from main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void changeString(char *stringptr, int sz);

int main(void)
{
    const int a_sz = 16;
    /* allocate memory for string & test successful allocation*/
    char *myString = malloc(a_sz);
    if (myString == NULL) {
        printf("Out of memory!\n");
        return(1);
    }

    /* put some initial characters into String */
    strcpy(myString, "Nonsense");
    /* print the original */
    printf("Old text: %s\n", myString);

    /* call function that will change the string */
    changeString(myString, a_sz);

    /* print out the modified string */
    printf("New text: %s\n", myString);

    /* free the memory allocated */
    free(myString);
}

void changeString(char *stringptr, int sz)
{
    /* text to copy into array */
    char *tocopy = "Sense";
    /* only copy text if it fits in allocated memory
       including one byte for a null terminator */
    if (strlen(tocopy) + 1 <= sz) {
        strcpy(stringptr, tocopy);
    }
}
```